# Cypress - how to find by text content?

Tags: javascript, cypress, end-to-end

In Cypress, I want to select a button from a group of buttons based on its text-content. How can I do it? Here is my approach:

```
export const getCustomerButton = () => getNavigationSidenav()
  .find('mat-expansion-panel-header')
  .each(($el, index, $list) => {
    const text = $el.find('.mat-content > mat-panel-title').text();
    if (text === 'Customer') {
      return $el;
    }
    return null;
  });
```

The problem I have now is that I have to filter out the nulls from the element array. Is there a less complicated way?

Comment: Do you have any HTML you can show. I see you already got your answer, but a bit of what you were trying to select would help.

Answer (score 98, accepted):

This code will yield the DOM element with `YOUR_BUTTON_CLASS` which contains text 'Customer'. Is that what you're looking for?

```js
cy.get('.YOUR_BUTTON_CLASS').contains('Customer');
```

[Here the documentation](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/contains.html#Syntax) for `.contains` cypress command.

Comment: Note that chaining commands like this can cause flakiness because the `get` is not retried after it finds something, even if none of the elements it finds contain 'Customer' (see [the docs](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/core-concepts/retry-ability.html#Only-the-last-command-is-retried))

Comment: Just doing `cy.get('Customer')` would try to yield an element *Customer* instead which is **not** what we require.

Comment: If you want to get the count of elements, better to use this refer this method https://stackoverflow.com/a/67699386/7469302

Answer (score 47):

Or maybe an even slicker solution is to use this:

```js
cy.contains('YOUR_BUTTON_CLASS', 'Customer');
```

This can be done since `contains()` can hold 2 arguments. And if it gets two arguments the first one is always the element and the second the text.

Comment: contains method returns only first found element

Comment: and even simpler is this: cy.contains('Customer')

Comment: This should be the default answer, due to the way Cypress handles query retries: "we recommend using cy.contains(selector, text) which is retried automatically as a single command."
https://docs.cypress.io/guides/core-concepts/retry-ability#Merging-queries

Answer (score 42):

Another option that's not mentioned in the previous answers here.

Use [testing-library/cypress-testing-library](https://github.com/testing-library/cypress-testing-library)

After the installation, just import it in cypress' `commands.js`:

```js
import '@testing-library/cypress/add-commands'
```

And in your tests

```js
cy.findAllByText("Jackie Chan").click();
cy.findByText("Button Text").should("exist");
cy.findByText("Non-existing Button Text").should("not.exist");
cy.findByLabelText("Label text", { timeout: 7000 }).should("exist");
cy.get("form").within(() => {
  cy.findByText("Button Text").should("exist");
});
cy.get("form").then((subject) => {
  cy.findByText("Button Text", { container: subject }).should("exist");
});
```

This is pretty straightforward and easy to use. We use this in our production site along with react testing library. Highly recommend :)

Comment: I was just wondering before I install this plugin, will `cy.findByText('Button').click()` yield same results as the built-in command `cy.contains('Button').click()`. If no, what is the difference?

Comment: I did a quick test and it looks like the returned buttons are slightly different, see this [screenshot](https://i.imgur.com/zTjdfmd.png) but they both work as they should

Comment: Is there a way for `findAllByText()` to only target visible elements?

Comment: Didn't test, but I think you can do a `.filter(':visible')`?

Answer (score 35):

The accepted answer "can" work. However: if the element is not visible on the first try, the element cannot be found in subsequent retries.

See: https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/3745

Cypress uses "Sizzle" as selector library - so this:

```js
cy.get('button:contains("FooBar")')`
```

would work in retries.

Answer (score 11):

There are multiple ways to do that

Syntaxes:

```js
cy.contains(content)
cy.contains(content, options)
cy.contains(selector, content)
cy.contains(selector, content, options)
```

Examples:

```
cy.contains('button', 'Customer')
cy.contains('.buttonClass', 'Customer')
cy.get('button:contains("Customer")')
cy.contains('Customer')
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to do it would be :

```
cy.get('Button_Class').contains('Button_Text')
```

In your case, the solution would be :

```
cy.get('.mat-content > mat-panel-title').contains('Customer')
```

There is a documentation for this [here](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/contains#Syntax).