# If else condition in Cypress

Tags: javascript, cypress, ui-automation

`.grid > languagefield` is the element of UI dropdown list
[image]

Depends on the language selected on this languagefield, it'll do something

This is what I have but Cypress doesn't hit `if` condition, something not right with `if (Lang == 'American English')`

```
const Date = Cypress.moment().add(-3, 'days').format('YYYY-MM-DD');
const DateUS = Cypress.moment(Date).format('MM/DD');
const DateUK = Cypress.moment(Date).format('DD/MM');
const Lang = '.grid > languagefield'
    
        if (Lang == 'American English') {
          //should get DateUS format  
        } else {
          //should get DateUK format 
         }
```

Thanks a lot!

[image]

Result of `cy.get('.grid > :nth-child(7)').invoke('text').then((txt) => { cy.log(txt) })`
[image]

More info
[image]

Comment: is this what you're looking for? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57533756/cypress-how-to-find-by-text-content

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can write something like:

```
cy.get('.grid > languagefield').invoke('text').then((txt) => {
  if (txt.trim() == 'American English') {
    //Do Something
  } else {
    //Do Something 
  }
})
```

OR, If you want to use [each()](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/each.html) to loop through the elements of the dropdown list and then find the text and perform some action, you can do something like:

```
cy.get('selctor').each(($el) => {
  if ($el.text().trim() == 'American English') {
    //Do Something
  } else {
    //Do Something 
  }
})
```

Comment: thanks for the answer but they both skip IF condition, and go straight to ELSE condition. for .invoke('text'). it skips .then(txt) & IF and goes to ELSE. for .each($el). skips IF and goes to ELSE. The language is set as American English currently. Do you have any idea? thanks

Comment: May be there is some extra space. I have updated my answer and added `trim()` to remove unwanted space. Can you try now ?

Comment: hi, thanks for the code sorry but they both still skip IF condition......

Comment: Is you website a public app, then may be I can take a look at it. Or a similar example will also do ?

Comment: sorry, it's not public but i can send a screenshot or something you need if you let me know what you need?

Comment: If you can post the screenshot of the DOM, that will also do.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/225929/discussion-between-alapan-das-and-user3601310).

Answer (score 1):

If the Profile section is visible, this will get you the text of the dropdown,

```
const language = Cypress.$('div[name="language"]')  // parent div for language selector
  .children().first()                               // first child is selected text 
  .text()

console.log(language);     // American English
```

The equivalent for Cypress aliasing

```
const languageDateFormats = {
  'American English': DateUS,
  'British English': DateUK,
  // other langauges
}

cy.visit('/profile');
cy.get('div[name="language"]')  // parent div for language selector
  .children().first()           // first child is selected text 
  .invoke('text')
  .as('language')

cy.visit('/timeline');
cy.get('@language').then(language => {
  const dateFormat = languageDateFormats[language];
  // test the timeline date format
})
```