# Cypress Automation - Cannot find button based on text

Tags: javascript, css-selectors, cypress, contains, automation-testing

I am learning Cypress and have been automating various websites for the last few weeks. However, I am having issues clicking a button based on it's class or text value. (Supposed to be easy, I know)

The button does not have an id and has a long class name:

```
message-component message-button no-children focusable sp_choice_type_11 last-focusable-el
```

The following image shows the full element:

[image]

I have tried the following code:

```
 cy.contains('Accept All').click() 

 cy.get('#message-component message-button no-children focusable sp_choice_type_11 last-focusable-el').contains('Accept All').click();
        
cy.get('button').contains('Accept All').click()
```

However, it just gives the same error and cannot find the button.

I have already checked the documentation for cypress and followed some advice off this post:

[Find by text content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57533756/cypress-how-to-find-by-text-content)

I also thought it may be that it loads the button after 4 seconds, so i upped the    `"defaultCommandTimeout"` to 7000. However, still no luck.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Much appreciated!

*** EDIT ****

Image of the error

[image]

Screenshot showing popup in cypress:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 'Accept All' button is inside an iframe. So you have to first go inside the iframe and then perform the click.

1. Install the [cypress-iframe](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cypress-iframe) plugin using the command `npm install -D cypress-iframe`
2. Go to `cypress/support/commands.js` and write `import 'cypress-iframe';`
3. In your test write:

```js
cy.iframe('[title="SP Consent Message"]').find('button[title="Accept All"]').click()
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I still get the error

Comment: Timed out retrying after 7000ms: Expected to find content: 'Accept All' within the selector: 'button' but never did.

Comment: Please add the error screenshot for this.

Comment: Edited answer with the image :)

Comment: And you are sure that the pop-up with the ''Accept All' button is displayed inside cypress? If yes how about you try using `cy.get('button[title="Accept All"]').should('be.visible').click({force: true})`?

Comment: Yes, I have added another screenshot into the edit. It shows, but the only thing I can think of is that the code is running before the button appears, but I have set the retry to 7 seconds. It shows in 1-2 at the most

Comment: You can add more timeout as well if you think time out is the issue. `cy.get('button[title="Accept All"], {timeout: 10000}').should('be.visible').click({force: true})`. this is a timeout for 10 seconds. You can add more and check.

Comment: That throws a syntax error:

Syntax error, unrecognized expression: button[title="Accept All"], {timeout: 10000}

Comment: Sorry my bad the syntax was wrong. here is the correct one `cy.get('button[title="Accept All"]', {timeout: 10000}).should('be.visible').click({force: true})`.

Comment: It still does not work :(

`Timed out retrying after 15000ms: Expected to find element: button[title="Accept All"], but never found it.`

It is the autotrader website, maybe they are blocking something?

www.autotrader.co.uk

Comment: Ok, let me try locally.

Comment: I have updated the answer. This should work.

Comment: Thanks, this worked. How did you notice it was in an iframe? Im new to this so curious

Comment: I inspected the element, and I saw that there is an iframe and inside that the `Accept All` button is there - https://imgur.com/7tzvrTD